# Codename One Background Music Playback

Tags: codenameone

I have challenges of playing background music in my Codename One application.
Can Someone who's familiar with this feature help me with a Java code example in Codename One?

Answer (score 1):

See the background music section in [the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/misc-features.html):

> Codename One supports playing music in the background (e.g. when the
>   app is minimized) which is quite useful for developers building a
>   music player style application.
>
> This support isn’t totally portable since the Android and iOS
>   approaches for background music playback differ a great deal. To get
>   this to work on Android you need to use the API:
>   `MediaManager.createBackgroundMedia()`.
>
> You should use that API when you want to create a media stream that
>   will work even when your app is minimized.
>
> For iOS you will need to use a special build hint:
>   `ios.background_modes=music`.
>
> Which should allow background playback of music on iOS and would work
>   with the `createBackgroundMedia()` method.